# Making websites available offline

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, web-sql, offline-storage

I am using HTML5 offline storage.  The goal is to make the whole site available offline.  So intuitively, no server requests means all the pages need to be on the client.  The only way I know of to accomplish such a task is to make the site into one page then show hide portions with jquery when the user "navigates".  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful that your jquery does not still point to the cloud.  You'll need to save the relevant .js files locally.

N.B.  If your whole site can be generated and saved as individual .html files then all you need to do is to save these files in the correct (relative) directory structure.

Answer (score 2):

The html 5 offline spec allows multiple pages to be saved offline so you don't need to put all your content onto one page.

EDIT: link to spec http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/offline.html

Comment: I haven't heard of a general HTML5 offline specification.  I am using only Web-SQL (iPad support only).  The spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/ .  Do you know if this applies to websql?

Comment: As you can read from the status of webdatabase: it's not maintained anymore and will probably be removed in the future. My link also works on the iPad/iPhone.

Comment: I know.  Apple currently backs the standard.  Run http://html5test.com/ in safari or watch WWDC 2011 videos.  +1 ty for link.

Comment: This answer linked me on to a couple of good resources - http://www.codemag.com/Article/1112051 and a link to html5rocks in the sidebar of that article on codemag.com